# Finding mean of a column of a data.table based on condition & replace other values with that mean

Tags: r, data.table

How to find the mean of a column where entries aren't -1 of a data.table ?
The name of the column is stored in a variable. Also how to assign the obtained mean value as the values where entries are -1 . The corresponding code for data.frame is :

```
col = "col_1"
mean_value = df[ df[,col]!=-1, col ]
df[ df[,col]==-1, col ] = mean_value
```

Sample data:

```
dt <- setDT(data.frame(col_1=c(-1,0,1,2,3)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with `get()` and `eval()`:

```
require(data.table)

mean_value <- mean(dt[get(col)!=-1,get(col)],na.rm=TRUE)

dt[get(col)==-1,eval(col):=mean_value]
```

Output:

```
   col_1
1:   1.5
2:   0.0
3:   1.0
4:   2.0
5:   3.0
```

Comment: @melwin_jose - okay, no problem; see the edit above.

Comment: `eval()` isn't necessarily needed; using `dt[get(col) == -1, (col) := mean_value]` works also

Comment: @Jaap - Thanks for the tip. That's what I was thinking too. I actually tried (col) the first time, but for some reason using only (col) produced an error. So I switched to the more explicit version eval(col).

Answer (score 0):

Using just Data.table

```
dt <- setDT(data.frame(col_1=c(-1,0,1,2,3)))
col = names(dt)
mean_value<-dt [ ! .(-1), lapply(.SD,mean), .SDcols = col,on=col]
dt[.(-1),(col):=mean_value,on=col]
```